# How to pass current date to a PHP function and use it in an SQL query's where condtion?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, unix-timestamp

I'm having a table named `users` in my MySQL database. There is a coulmn named `user_reg_date(bigint(12))` in this table used to store the registration date for that user.

This column is storing the registration date in UNIX Timestamp format. I'm a newbie for this UNIX Timestamp and date manipulation in PHP.
Now my requirement is that I want to pass current date to a function and fetch the count of users whose registration date is current date(i.e. the count of users registered today).

I don't know how to pass the current date to the function and fetch the count of users who have their registration date as current date. I'm giving my PHP function code below.

```
/*The argument `$todays_date` I'm passing is dummy, please guide me how to pass the date also*/
    function GetRegisteredUsersCount($todays_date) { 
        $sql  = " SELECT count(*) as registered_users_count FROM ".TBL_USERS;
        $sql .= " WHERE user_reg_date ='".$todays_date."' ";

        $this->mDb->Query( $sql);
        $data = $this->mDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);

        return $data;    
      }
```

Comment: This will come back to bite you in time. This is an easy problem if you're using MySQL DATE format in your columns. Change it if you can.

Comment: @MikeW:No I can't change the date format. I can't do any change to database design.

Answer (score 2):

Since your date is stored as an integer, you need to query using a range, between the start of today and up to (not including) the start of the next day.

```
$today = strtotime('today');
$tomorrow = strtotime('+1 day', $today);

$sql .= sprintf(
    " WHERE user_reg_date >= %d AND user_reg_date < %d", 
    $today, 
    $tomorrow
);
```

See also: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Btw, it's recommended to run this on a platform that uses 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

You should change user_reg_date(bigint(12)) field type to timestamp and set it default as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Whenever a new user will register it will automatically pick the current date time. And when you want to find out how many user registered today then just hit a query:-

```
$sql  = "SELECT count(*) as registered_users_count from tb_users where datediff(CURDATE(),DATE(user_reg_date)) =0"
```

Comment: :I can't make any change to the database design. So i cant change the datatype(bigint(12) to timestamp).